# Poller to read from Amazon SNS Topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Can we have a poller for SNS Topic which would get all the messages from SNS Topic in regular intervals, like we can have for SQS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon SNS is a Publish/Subscribe system. When a message is sent to a topic, it is immediately sent out to all relevant subscribers. Messages are *not* retained in Amazon SNS.

If you wish to retain messages for later polling, you can use Amazon SQS.

However, **Amazon SQS can subscribe to an Amazon SNS topic**. This would allow you to store messages for later polling. The flow would be:

```
Message -> SNS Topic -> SQS Queue subscription -> Available for polling by worker
```